# Ошибка при работе с moviepy

Tags: python, обработка-изображений, moviepy

Необходимо обрезать видео если оно длиной больше 30 секунд (с 30 секудны и до конца видео отрезок не нужен ,также длина видео разная поэтому точное значение окончания видео не известно и меняется).

При запуске кода (ниже) происходит только две вещи:

1. Cохраняется только аудио (даже если добавляю кодек), либо вообще выдает ошибку, что не удалось определить длину видео.
   ОС windows 10, **ffmpeg** установлен (судя по документации, ставится автоматом, также скачал еще один новой версии и в конфиге сделал к нему путь)
2. Появляется куча ошибок от библиотеки.

Требуется только обрезка видео если оно длительностью более определенного времени (30-60 сек). Может есть какие-то другие библиотеки для этой цели ?

```py
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip, concatenate_videoclips , clips_array, vfx, AudioFileClip
import ffmpeg
import os

# пишем путь к файлу
files = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\Desktop\\eredità\\AvtoTT\\videos\\")

# создаем пустой список в переменной video , в которую будет передаваться имя файла
video = []

# цикл for с переменной videos (новая переменная ,которая будет перебирать значения(видосы) в папке с видео

for videos in files:
    print(videos)
    if videos.endswith(".mp4"):  # если строка которую мы передаем в videos  заканчивается на vid
        video.append(videos)  # то передаем в конец списка
if len(video) == 0:  # len() - количество элементов в списке ,если значение равно 0 ,то это ошибка
    print('ошибка/n')
else:  # если в списке имеется видео  ,то запускается цикл
    for videos in video:
        print("пошел процесс...")
        # выясняем длину видео
        video = VideoFileClip("C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\Desktop\\eredità\\AvtoTT\\videos\\" +videos)
        # обрезаем видео с 30 секунд до конца (round функция ,которая округляет число )
        video = video.cutout(15,round(30))
        # сохранение нового видео в файле
        video.write_videofile("videos\\vid.mp4"+videos , fps=30,)
```

ошибки которые выдает :

```
Moviepy - Building video videos\vid0.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in vid0TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3
t:   0%|          | 0/900 [00:00<?, ?it/s, now=None]MoviePy - Done.
Moviepy - Writing video videos\vid0.mp4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 136, in write_frame
    self.proc.stdin.write(img_array.tobytes())
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\eredità\Pes.py", line 31, in <module>
    video.write_videofile("videos\\"+videos , fps=30)
  File "<decorator-gen-55>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-54>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 135, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-53>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 300, in write_videofile
    ffmpeg_write_video(self, filename, fps, codec,
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 228, in ffmpeg_write_video
    writer.write_frame(frame)
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py", line 180, in write_frame
    raise IOError(error)
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file videos\vid0.mp4:

 b'videos\\vid0.mp4: No such file or directory\r\n'
                                                    
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Скопируйте отдельным блоком какие ошибки выдаёт.

Comment: не в комментарии, отредактируйте вопрос и поместите в code block. Это читать невозможно.

Comment: Прошу прощение ,первый раз на форуме ,не заметил функцию редактирования . Изменил в вопросе

Comment: А почему код в ошибке отличается от кода в вопросе? Может у вас не только строка там другая, но и ещё что-то в коде?

Comment: Могли бы вы уточнить , в каком месте именно код отличается от ошибки (я просто не так давно изучаю питон ,возможно что-то не замечаю) ? Ошибку которую я вставил , выдается при запуске кода в вопросе ,более в скрипте  у меня ничего нет . (в вопросе я только удалил пути к файлу ).

Comment: Сейчас внес  правку , вот так  выглядит полный код ,который я запускаю и выводятся данные ошибки 
Причем при запуске данного кода ,создается файл формата мр3 , с аудио дорожкой и тайминг совпадает ,но видеодорожки нет и как я понимаю, именно при рендере видео выходят ошибки из файлов  скриптов в библиотеки Moviepy

Comment: Сейчас вроде совпадает, ок. Так, а что вы пытаетесь всё-таки сделать? `cutout` выкидывает из видео кусок с первого указанного тайминга по последний указанный и возвращает получившееся видео с учётом этого выреза. При этом вы даже не проверяете - какого у вас размера видео, может эти тайминги 15 и 30 за границей видео вообще, поэтому и ошибка такая? Может вам вообще какая-то другая операция нужна?

Comment: У меня максимально простая задача . Есть куча видео разной длины  (все больше 1 минуты ) , необходимо обрезать каждое видео так ,чтобы оно шло 30 секунд ,вместо 1 минуты + . Например,видео оригинальное идет 1:00 , то в новом видео должны остаться только первые 30 секунд .

Comment: В идеале конечно бы хотелось .чтобы скрип проверял видео в папке 1  ,если видео короче 1 минуты ,то он просто переносит в папку 2 , если видео дольше 59 секуд ,то он обрезал все что дольше 59 секудны и  сохранял  в папку 2 .Но для меня такие манипуляции пока сложноваты ,хотелось бы разобраться для начала просто с обрезкой видео .

Comment: Короче, попробуйте так: `if video.duration > 30: video = video.subclip(0, 30)`, это на случай 30 секунд, а то в следующем комментарии у вас уже 59 секунд, вы уж определитесь.

Comment: не могли бы вы посказать в какую часть кода вставить данную строку ? Вставил после  `video = VideoFileClip`  и ситуация осталась таже

Comment: Вместо `video = video.cutout(15,round(30))`, естественно

Comment: Значит я правильно понял .К сожалению ,не помогло . Сохраняется только один 30 секундный  файл в формате МР3 , но видеодорожка также отсутсвует ,далее опять ошибки библиотеки  и как я понимаю , жалуется на отсутсвие файла в папке videos ,но файл там имеется и название у него vid0 .(Ошибки обновил в вопросе)

Comment: Так, а зачем у вас список с видео и текущий файл с видео называются одинаково `video`? Нет ли с этим проблемы? Я не уверен, что `for` при этом не сломается. И ещё мне не нравится, что выходной файл будет иметь название `videos\\vid.mp4vid0.mp4`, сделайте нормальное название, и хорошо бы с полным путём, а не с относительным.

Comment: благодарю , видимо действительно была проблема с названием текущего файла ,поменял имя и процесс пошел .
Я новенький на форуме ,не подскажите как могу вас тут  отблагодарить за потраченое время ?

Comment: @Mousa Этот форум бескорыстный, тут помогают просто из интереса и для собственного саморазвития. )  Если не лениво - оформите собственный ответ с работающим кодом и напишите, в чём была проблема, возможно это кому-то ещё в будущем поможет.

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема была с названием текущего файла "video" (совпадало с названием списка "video").
рабочий код:

```
        # Импортируем библеотеки
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip, concatenate_videoclips , clips_array, vfx, AudioFileClip
import ffmpeg
import os

# пишем путь к файлу
files = os.listdir("путь")

# создаем пустой список в переменной video , в которую будет передаваться имя файла
video = []
i= 0
# цикл for с переменной videos (новая переменная ,которая будет перебирать значения(видосы) в папке с видео

for videos in files:
    print(videos)
    if videos.endswith(".mp4"):  # если строка которую мы передаем в videos  заканчивается на vid
        video.append(videos)  # то передаем в конец списка
if len(video) == 0:  # len() - количество элементов в списке ,если значение равно 0 ,то это ошибка
    print('ошибка/n')
else:  # если в списке имеется видео  ,то запускается цикл

    for videos in video:
        print("пошел процесс...")
        # выясняем длину видео и обрезаем 

     a = VideoFileClip("путь" +videos)
        
        if a.duration > 30:
           a = a.subclip(0, 30)
           print (a)
        # сохранение нового видео в файле
        a.write_videofile(f"C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\Desktop\\eredità\\AvtoYT\\готовое\\vid{i}.mp4" , fps=30)
        if i == i:
            i+=1 "
```

Отдельная благодарность- CrazyElf за помощь с решением вопроса .

Comment: Вывод: на будущее постарайтесь давать переменным более осмысленные имена, а не какие попало, и следите что у вас в каких переменных, чтобы не было пересечения. Грамотное наименование переменных очень облегчает работу с кодом.